# MainStoryboard disappeared after moving project folder

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode4.5, recovery

I just tried to make a copy of an X-code project (perhaps ironically, for back up purposes) by alt+dragging to another folder.

Instead I accidentally just dragged it and X-code complained about this (I know, I should've closed X-Code before attempting to copy the folder) so I moved it back immediately.

X-code insisted it either re-save or close, so I opted for close.

When I reopened it, my MainStoryboard was gone (red typeface in the explorer).

Anyone know if it's possible to retrieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much help to anyone but switching the Mac on and off again restored the file, which was a nice surprise.

Comment: Well, seems to be a Solved Question, you should mark your own answer as Accepted by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: I would if the site would let me. "You can accept your own answer tomorrow."

Answer (score 1):

- Are the files in the project directory?
  If so, you can try to delete them from XCode and re-add them to the project.
- It could a problem linked to the localization. You should try to remove any other langages.
- Do you use any souce management tool (svn, git, snapshots or Time Machine)?
  If so you can maybe take a look at it to retrieve a recent version of the files.

Comment: 1) Yes, the MainStoryboard file is in the project folder. Took me a while to find it - it's in the `en.lproj` folder. Adding it again doesn't seem to be working though.
2) I think en.lproj is the language folder? If so, it appears to be the only one.
3) I started this project intending to use snapshots but they've turned out to be a worse than useless distraction. I'll be using git in all future projects.

Comment: Well, whaddayknow? The old "switch off, switch on again" fixed it.